# Two svgs next to each other horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Is it possible to have multiple SVGs that are next to each other horizontally. I know that when you append a SVG in D3, it appends in below the previous SVG. But now I have the previous SVG on half the page, and I want to translate this SVG from below the previous SVG to the right of the previous SVG. I tried using the transform-->translate attribute on the second svg but it did not work:

```
var secondSVG= d3.select("#div1").append("svg").attr("width",960).attr("transform"),"translate(500, -500)");
```

Comment: If this is your actual code, you have a typo in the end, where there is a `)` to much after `"transform"`.

Comment: oh just ignore that. I did not copy and paste. I just made a mistake when manually typing the code onto this website. That is not the reason why I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome 24, IE10, and FF17 this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbj8G/) worked as expected. The key seemed to be setting the `width` and `height` stylesheet properties.

HTML:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="190" id="svg1">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180"
  style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;">
</svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="190" id="svg2">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180"
  style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;">
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
svg
{
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
}
```

Comment: Uhm. Could you happen to think of a particular reason that if the combined width of my two svgs is greater than 960, it puts the second svg below the first one. However, if the comvined width of my two svgs is less than or equal to 960, than they appear next to each other horizontally.

Comment: @user1943827 It most likely is related to the browser window size or your screen size. The browser renders based on the size of its window.

Answer (score 0):

Awhile back I wanted to do something similar, but I eventually settled on using a single svg element with two internal g elements, one of them transformed to the right. You can see the eventual finished product [here](http://hyperphor.com/election/scatterstates.html).

Answer (score 0):

General idea: Wrap each SVG in a div element that is displayed as inline-block.
This works with the following approach that I personally like anyway.

- Set the width and height attributes of the SVGs to 100%.
- "Inner impact": Specify the size of the drawing area (which the units of the elements in the SVGs, like circle, relate to) with the viewBox attribute; this typically goes together with the preserveAspectRatio attribute.
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio
- "Outer impact": The SVGs will adapt to the size of their container. Style it (width and/or height) according to your wishes. Of course you need enough horizontal space.

Minimal example:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 42%">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="-80 -45 160 90" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="39">
</svg>
</div>
<!-- Just a copy from above. Right of (not below) the previous SVG. -->
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 42%">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="-80 -45 160 90" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="39">
</svg>
</div>
```